# Help find algorithm for array-based task

Tags: cc.complexity-theory

Given array if numbers a[1..n]. Pair of numbers (i, j) is interesting, if i < j и a[i] > 2*a[j]. How to count number of interesting pairs in O(n*logn)?

What is the solution?

My solution is not quite O(nlogn).
Sort array and save in sorted arrau initial indices of values. For each element x of initial array find by binary search element x/2 -1 and its position in new array. Then maybe all elements that are in left part of array are possible pairs for x. Compare their indices with index of x.
Sort - nlogn.
Binary search - logn. For each element then in sum nlogn.
But comparing of indices can be n. And it will became n*n*logn.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a homework assignment, so here is how to look for an answer in this kind of problems. It isn't a beautiful solution, but it's a general solution for a huge class of problems.

You're asking, for each index j, "how many indices i $\in$ [1..j-1] such that a[i] < X ?" where X is 2a[j]. For this kind of question, there are data structures that can answer in $\log(n)$ time, if they have been built before. And, you're lucky, because when changing from the range [1..j-1] to the range [1..j], you can update the data structure in $\log(n)$ time.

So your algorithm is :

> Initialize data structure S
>
> nbInteresting = 0
>
> For each j from 1 to n:
>
> > nbInteresting += S.request(2a[j])
> >
> > S.add(a[j])
>
> return nbInteresting

On purpose, I won't give you the exact data structure, because I guess it is the important part of the assignment, but things like binary trees are structures that work in a lot of situations.

Good luck !